# How to get reference of already running AWS EC2 instance in my CDK stack/app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I want to add an Alert to the CPU usage metric of an already running EC2 instance using AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK). The version of CDK I'm using is 2.60.0. But I found no solution in the sample examples or on google searches.

Below is the Stack I've tried. It uses the existing VPC but creates a new EC2 instance instead of referring to existing ones.

```
class CloudwatchHighCpuUsageAlertStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "MyVPC", vpc_id="vpc-xyz")  # Uses existing VPC

        instance = ec2.Instance(  # Creates new Instance instead of getting one with Instance ID (i-abc)
            self,
            id="i-abc",
            instance_type=ec2.InstanceType("t2.micro"),
            machine_image=ec2.MachineImage.latest_amazon_linux(),
            vpc=vpc,
        )
```

Comment: I am in the same boat, for example VPC can be pulled by calling Vpc.FromLookup, what is the equivalent for EC2??? A very simple basic question and yet no answer yet!!

Comment: Apparently this is not supported out of the box with AWS CDK. I've ran into a similar issue.

Notice that the "id" you're providing here is a CloudFormat ID which will show-up in your CloudFormation UI, and it is not related to the instance ID at all.

I think one might have to work around with boto3. I'll post an answer if I manage to do it myself.

Comment: Sadly, I couldn't find an answer here. I couldn't find either any examples in AWS CDK documentation that implement this look-up.